# Native Windows API link problem on Qt + win32 + mingw

Tags: windows, qt, mingw

I am trying to use native windows API with Qt using mingw toolset. There are link problems with some functions. What happens? Is this a bug with mingw name mangling?

```
#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
    HWND hwnd = QWidget::winId();
    HDC hdcEMF  = CreateEnhMetaFile(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL ) ;
    Rectangle(hdcEMF,100,100,200,200);
    HENHMETAFILE hemf = CloseEnhMetaFile(hdcEMF);
    OpenClipboard(hwnd);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_ENHMETAFILE,hemf);
    CloseClipboard();
#else
```

The errors:

undefined reference to `CreateEnhMetaFileW@16'

undefined reference to `Rectangle@20'

undefined reference to `CloseEnhMetaFile@4'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions `CreateEnhMetaFileW()` and `CloseEnhMetaFile()` are defined in the static library Gdi32.lib, so you have to make sure to link against that.  Try adding `-lgdi32` to the end of your command line you're using to compile.  If that doesn't work, you might have to specify the full path to Gdi32.lib by adding `-L/path/to/folder/containing/the/library -lgdi32` instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Windows API in a Qt app then there's no need to declare WinAPI functions extern "C", just include:

```
#include <qt_windows.h>
```

In your project file (.pro) add the libraries you use:

```
LIBS += -luser32 -lshell32 -lgdi32
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the functions are included, but getting mangled due to the C++ assumption.

Look into the extern C { } declaration.  It's intended to declare functions that should not be name mangled to account for polymorphism / overloading. (IE two functions with the same name).

Answer (score 0):

@torn your solution worked for me.

I wanted to use a win32 api call in my qt application.

the #include 
the #include your-win32-api-header

and finally the LIBS += -llibrary name.

Note that you might have to give -L for the right paths too.

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer, just a comment on @torn's answer.