# Qt - get all opened windows title

Tags: windows, winapi, qt

how can i check whether a specific window is open or not. I only got part of the window's name. i thinking of using EnumWindows() in QT console app but i get a few errors stating "main.obj:-1: error:  unresolved external symbol **imp__GetWindowTextW@12 referenced in function "int __stdcall EnumWindowsProc(struct HWND** *,long)" (?EnumWindowsProc@@YGHPAUHWND__@@J@Z)"

Below is my sample code

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lParam) {
    char buff[255];

    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) {
       GetWindowText(hWnd, (LPWSTR) buff, 254);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm making a couple of assumptions here, but are you linking against user32.lib?

Comment: check out [Native Windows API link problem on Qt + win32 + mingw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267672)

Comment: I manage to compile my QT apps without error by adding #include <stdlib.h>

Answer (score 2):

That's a linker error rather than a compile error.

You have correctly included `windows.h` but you also need to add the import libraries to your linker options. All three Win32 functions in your sample code require you to link `user32.lib`.

Answer (score 0):

EnumWindowsProc is not from Qt, it's a windows API function, you need to include windows.h

I did not use Qt, and the code can pass complie, but the output seems NOT right. Anyway, here's my code

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
char buff[255];
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lParam)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
    {
       GetWindowText(hWnd, (LPWSTR) buff, 254);
    }
    return TRUE;
}


int main()
{
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i != 254; ++i)
        cout << buff[i];
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Lynnooi your code works in my application... try not use Qt, use the native C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Application.OpenForms["FormName"]
```

To check if the form is open or not.

Comment: i would like to get all opened application windows including those which is not QT application